# How to use AnimatePresence for clean entry and exit?

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I am trying to make a clean entry/exit animation in my next app using Framer Motion's AnimatePresence component. I have tried using the delay component but only works for one component. For the other components, they just vanish without any animation. The expected behavior and current behavior is shown below:

[Expected & Working behavior](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SmBXXQpiRRH1YSm2gyyjqLbHQs-G-ITB/view?usp=share_link)

[Current & Not Working Behavior](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YWryf0JI47eNChwaBDQSFF3io2nMIyWu/view?usp=share_link)

The code of the components is below:

```
<AnimatePresence>
                  {isAboutVisible && (
                    <motion.div
                      initial={{ x: 1050, opacity: 0 }}
                      animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
                      transition={{
                        duration: 1.5,
                        ...(isSkillsVisible || isProjectsVisible
                          ? { delay: 1.5 }
                          : {}),
                      }}
                      exit={{ x: 1050, opacity: 0 }}
                    >
                      <About />
                    </motion.div>
                  )}
                </AnimatePresence>
                <AnimatePresence>
                  {isSkillsVisible && (
                    <motion.div
                      initial={{ x: 1050, opacity: 0 }}
                      animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
                      transition={{
                        duration: 1.5,
                        delay: 1.5,
                      }}
                      exit={{ x: 1050, opacity: 0 }}
                    >
                      <Skills />
                    </motion.div>
                  )}
                </AnimatePresence>
                <AnimatePresence>
                  {isProjectsVisible && (
                    <motion.div
                      initial={{ x: 1050, opacity: 0 }}
                      animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
                      transition={{ duration: 1.5, delay: 1.5 }}
                      exit={{ x: 1050, opacity: 0 }}
                    >
                      <Projects />
                    </motion.div>
                  )}
                </AnimatePresence>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think all conditions must be in one AnimatePresence and mode="wait" prop must be added to it

sth like this :

```
 <AnimatePresence  mode="wait" initial={false}>
          {isAboutVisible && (
            <motion.div
              key="about"
              initial={{ x: 1050, opacity: 0 }}
              animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
              transition={{
                duration: 1.5,
                ...(isSkillsVisible || isProjectsVisible ? { delay: 1.5 } : {}),
              }}
              exit={{ x: 1050, opacity: 0 }}
            >
              <About />
            </motion.div>
          )}
          {isSkillsVisible && (
            <motion.div
              key="skills"
              initial={{ x: 1050, opacity: 0 }}
              animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
              transition={{
                duration: 1.5,
                delay: 1.5,
              }}
              exit={{ x: 1050, opacity: 0 }}
            >
              <Skills />
            </motion.div>
          )}
          {isProjectsVisible && (
            <motion.div
              key="projects"
              initial={{ x: 1050, opacity: 0 }}
              animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
              transition={{ duration: 1.5, delay: 1.5 }}
              exit={{ x: 1050, opacity: 0 }}
            >
              <Projects />
            </motion.div>
          )}
        </AnimatePresence>
```

and as @ivanatias said, for keeping track of the element's presence, a key must be added to each animated element

Comment: OP also needs to include a unique `key` for each animated element so framer-motion can keep track of the element's presence in the tree.

Comment: that's right, thank you for mentioning it, let me update my answer

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh I also forgot one thing: the exitBeforeEnter prop is deprecated and has been switched to mode="wait" as of framer-motion v8.2.4

Comment: aha, I didn't know that, thanks for telling me :)

Comment: According to the official docs, AnimatePresence currently only renders a single child at a time. Although this works, it might cause odd behaviors, you will get a warning in the console.